# Robot Framework. Wait until keyword succeeds 5m 10s {keyword {keyword {keyword}}}

Tags: robotframework

I wanna use a keyword 'Wait until keyword succeeds' in this way:

**Wait until keyword succeeds  5m  10s  {keyword {keyword {keyword} args} args}**

How can I do that or what are alternatives?

I trying to pass arguments in this way

**Wait until keyword succeeds  5m  10s (custom keyword  (custom keyword)  args)  args)**
is it also possible?

Answer (score 0):

[`Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) takes only one keyword with arguments that are gonna be passed to this one keyword.

> How can I do that or what are alternatives?

- build your own keyword that allows you to do so => probably time consuming
- use `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` multiple times one after the other like so:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    5m 10s    keyword1
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    5m 10s    keyword1
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    5m 10s    keyword1
```